# Android: How to draw an array of points to a canvas

Tags: android-canvas, android-view, ondraw

I am reading in an array of points from another activity and creating a path from the points. I have a custom view called "DrawCanvas" that extends View. Currently the code is projecting a blank white canvas. Could someone help me understand why the canvas is not drawing the path?

PreviewActivity.java

```
public class Preview extends Activity{

Canvas newCanvas = new Canvas();
MyPointsList object;

protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState){
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    getIntentData();
    Path path = new Path();
    if(object.getArrayList().get(0) != null){
        for(int i = 0; i < object.getArrayList().size(); i++){
            path.moveTo(object.getMyPoint(i).getX(), object.getMyPoint(i).getY());  
            path.lineTo(object.getMyPoint(i).getX(), object.getMyPoint(i).getY());
        }
    }

    FrameLayout canvas1  = new FrameLayout(this);

    DrawCanvas view;
    view = new DrawCanvas(Preview.this);
    view.onDraw(newCanvas, path);
    canvas1.addView(view);

    setContentView(canvas1);
}   


public void getIntentData(){
    Intent i = this.getIntent();
    if(i.hasExtra("parcel")){
        Bundle b = getIntent().getExtras();
        object = b.getParcelable("parcel");

        if(object != null){
            Log.d("Debug", object.getArrayList().get(5).getX() + " " + object.getArrayList().get(5).getY());

        }
        else if(object == null){
            Log.d("Debug", "Object is equal to Null");  
        }
    }       
}
```

DrawCanvas.java

```
public class DrawCanvas extends View {

public DrawCanvas(Context context) {
    super(context);
    // TODO Auto-generated constructor stub
}

public void onDraw(Canvas canvas, Path path){
    super.onDraw(canvas);
    canvas.drawARGB(255,255,255,255);

    Paint black = new Paint();
    black.setColor(Color.BLACK);
    black.setStyle(Paint.Style.STROKE);
    black.setStrokeJoin(Paint.Join.ROUND);
    black.setStrokeCap(Paint.Cap.ROUND);
    black.setStrokeWidth(3);

    canvas.drawPath(path, black);
}
```

}

Answer (score 1):

You don't override the right `onDraw(Canvas canvas)` method in your custom view. As I see it, you pass to the super `onDraw` an empty canvas. Then, you're adding your paths but don't invalidate the view in order to draw your modifications.
And, other thing that prevents your results to be visible, you add the `DrawView` after calling your `onDraw`. My guess, the view will "reset" its lifecycle (`onMeasure` -> `onLayout` -> `onDraw` ...) but with its basics initialization. (I'm not sure about that tho). So all your modifications won't be stored.
Besides, you shouldn't allocate new objects at the time you're drawing something. This will consume to much memory each time the view is invalidate.

Therefore, try to initialize the `Paint` object at start:

```
private Paint paint;
private Path path;

public DrawCanvas(Context c) {
    super(c);
    init();
}

public DrawCanvas(Context c, AttributesSet a) {
    super(c, a);
    init();
}

private void init() {
    // create your paint object
    paint = new Paint();
    paint.setColor(Color.BLACK);
    ...
}
```

Following by your `Path`s initialization:

```
public void setPath(Path path) {
    // store your new path
    this.path = path;
    // invalidate the view to call onDraw()
    invalidate();
}
```

Finally, override the real `onDraw` method and draw your logic:

```
@Override
public void onDraw(Canvas canvas) {
    if (paint == null || path == null)
        return;

    canvas.drawPath(path, paint);
}
```

Now you can set your new `Path` in `onCreate()` as follows:

```
setContentView(canvas1);

DrawCanvas draw = new DrawCanvas(this);
canvas1.addView(draw);
draw.setPath(path);
```

If you have "heavy" treatments as Path object, you should consider to call `postInvalidate()` because `invalidate()` will be call in the main thread.